# Flask - Redirect and passing arguments to the function

Tags: python, redirect, flask, arguments

I'm implementing languages menu into my application.
The main URL returns the default english page and from there you can select other languages through a menu.

This is the code:

```
@app.route('/')
def home_page(language='en'):
    return render_template(f"homepage - {language}.html")


@app.route('/lang=<language>')
def home_page_language(language):
    return render_template(f"homepage - {language}.html")
```

After you select a language, the URL is `foo.foo/lang=foo`,
So I was wondering if there is a way to redirect to the `home_page` function and in the same time pass a language argument so that the URL stays clean (`foo.foo`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is serve the same template with the new `language` setting, then it helps to know that `home_page()` view is *just a function*. You can just call it:

```
@app.route('/lang=<language>')
def home_page_language(language):
    return home_page(language)
```

Better still, you can register views under multiple routes, you don't actually need a second function here; just move the `/lang=<language>` registration to the `home_page()` function:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/lang=<language>')
def home_page(language='en'):
    return render_template(f"homepage - {language}.html")
```

Now `/` will use `'en'`, and `/lang=foobar` will call that same function with `language='foobar'`.

If you were hoping to actually *redirect* the browser back to the `/` URL (using a 30x Moved response), but at the same time keep the language setting, then you lose the information you stored in the URL path and have to record the language preference *somewhere else*. Most multilingual sites commonly store your language preference in a dedicated cookie, but you could also use the [Flask `session` object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions) (which also is cookie based in the default setup).

To redirect to a different URL, use the [`flask.redirect()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=redirect#flask.redirect), then attach your cookie to the response object that that produces (using [`Response.set_cookie()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=redirect#flask.Response.set_cookie).

Your homepage will need to look for the language setting in the same cookie, it will *not* be part of the URL; I used a dedicated cookie here to store this information:

```
from flask import redirect, request, url_for

@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    language = request.cookies.get('language', 'en')
    return render_template(f"homepage - {language}.html")

@app.route('/lang=<language>')
def home_page_language(language):
    redirected = redirect(url_for('home_page'))
    redirected.set_cookie('language', language)
    return redirected
```

If you were to store this information in the session object, you don't have to manually update the redirect response, the Flask framework handles that transparently for you:

```
from flask import session, redirect, url_for

@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    language = session.get('language', 'en')
    return render_template(f"homepage - {language}.html")

@app.route('/lang=<language>')
def home_page_language(language):
    session['language'] = language
    return redirect(url_for('home_page'))
```

Comment: Thanks, but still in the browser the user will see /lang=foo because he wasn't redirected to (/), and that's what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @YanivK.: right, that wasn't clear from your question. You can't do that without also storing that information *somewhere else*, like in a cookie.

Comment: Ok I'll have to learn about it because it's new to me,but it sounds promising. thanks!

Comment: By the way, it seems at first glance like `home_page()` will always return `en` because it's hard-coded. Are you sure it shouldn't be an argument with a default value?

Comment: @YanivK.: It is not hard-coded. It is only a *default*, when no explicit value is passed in.

Comment: @YanivK.: `session.get('language', 'en')` and `request.cookies.get('language', 'en')` only return `'en'` if the key `'language'` / cookie `'language'` is missing, see the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for details. In the no-redirect example (first part of my answer), the `/` URL causes `home_page()` to be called (setting `language='en'` to the default), but for `/language=foobar` Flask calls `home_page(language='foobar')`, thus replacing the default value with the `'foobar'` string.

Comment: @YanivK. as for the redirect / cookie requirement: you have to realise that the HTTP protocol is **stateless**. Each request should be seen as a new connection, from a random client. *Everything* you need to know about that client needs to be part of that request. The request has a URL, that's one piece of information, but you can use headers to learn more about the cilent. Cookies are one way of asking the client to attach more information to their next request, and if you don't want the language to be in the URL, then cookies are a good place to put that same information instead.